# Cannot resolve reference in JSON Schema using AJV - CLI

Tags: json, validation, schema

I'm trying to build a JSON schema (draft-06) for an existing JSON data file.  The schema has gotten to big to fit in a single file and I am trying to break it up into multiple files.  However I keep getting the error `can't resovle refrence sectionTableSchema.txt from id http://somesite/section`

I've made the following files and placed them in the same directory. These files are not hosted on a webserver.

**settingsSchema.txt:**

```
{
  "title":"Settings",
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "$id":"http://somesite/settingsSchema.txt",
  "properties":{
    "section":{
      ...
      ...
      ...
      "$id":"/section",
      "items":{
        "oneOf":[
          {"$ref":"#/sectionTableSchema.txt"},
          {"$ref":"#/sectionNonTableSchema.txt"}
        ]
      },
      "type":"array"
    }
  },
  "type":"object"
}
```

**sectionTableSchema.txt**

```
{
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "$id":"http://somesite/sectionTableSchema.txt",
  "definitions":{},
  "properties":{
    ....
    ....
    ....
  }
  "type":"object"
}
```

I think part of my issue is that I don't understand the `$id` and `$ref` keywords enough to know what is going on between absolute uri, relative uri, json-pointers and the like.

Answer (score 2):

### What happens?

In the OP's example `"$ref":"#/sectionTableSchema.txt"` means "inside **current** schema file, get JSON property called `sectionTableSchema.txt` from root element".

---

### How $ref works?

`$ref` can be presented in two parts:

- Before "#" sign you can specify URI (in simple words, a path) of schema file. If you start `$ref` from "#" sign and, therefore, don't provide URI of schema file, this means you want to take schemas from current file.
- After "#" sign you can provide a JSON pointer, e. g. a path to the property in JSON that is located in specified file (or current file, depending on provided schema URI before "#" sign).

The same information can be found in [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#id1).

---

### How to reference other file correctly?

As I understand, **JSON Schema drafts say** you can specify a valid URI to schema file. But URIs cannot be relative, so there is no standard-defined way of referencing files with relative paths. However, in practice **a lot of tools provide abilities** to do this, though they are not a part of the standard and may differ from tool to tool.

**In AJV** you can write your reference as `"$ref":"ANY-ID-YOU-WANT"` and use `ajv.addSchema(schemaJson, 'ANY-ID-YOU-WANT')` method, where `schemaJson` is a variable with `require`'d `sectionTableSchema.txt` content.

Comment: Absolutely worked for me. Thanks